# Do the antlers re-grow in the same pattern every year?

Tags: zoology, mathematical-models, software, imaging

I am a software engineer and I am trying to develop a system to identify a deer by its photograph.

Most deers lose their antlers every year. I would like to know if they re-grow in the same pattern next year and if yes, then what are the measurements that are of interest here?

Any pointers for me? Any software that can help me in recognizing a deer?

Comment: This has effectively been superseded by your subsequent question - in future you might want to consider using the [edit] function :)